# How do I limit the users a specific user can run commands in linux?

Tags: linux, user-management, user-accounts

I have 2 user accounts, **foo** and **bar**

I want to allow user **foo** to execute commands as root and any other user ie:

> sudo su root -c'./run-my-script'
>
> sudo su bar -c'./another-script'
>
> sudo su another -c'./yet-another-script

I also want to allow user **bar** to execute commands as other user but only a subset and not root ie:

> sudo su bar -c'./run-my-script'

but not

> sudo su root -c'./run-my-script'

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's certainly possible.

Firstly you need to fix your usage of sudo, to execute a command as a user other than root (the default) with sudo the syntax is: `sudo -u username command`

You can then lock down the users whose identity a user can assume via the `/etc/sudoers` config file, eg a fully privileged user looks like:

`jim    ALL=(ALL) ALL`

Whereas a user with restrictions looks like:

`jim     ALL=(admin,bill) ALL`

Which means if I try and execute a command as a user who isn't in the list I get denied:

```
jim@mybox:~$ sudo -u nobody whoami
Sorry, user jim is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/whoami' as nobody on mybox.
```

Comment: Thats great thanks. However I would also want to allow a user to su to specific other users also, is that possible?

Comment: Read the answer above again? 'admin' and 'bill' are usernames, not groups.